# Getting authlogic_facebook_connect to create users in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-plugins, facebooker

I'm using the [Authlogic Facebook Connect plugin](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect) on my site. After a bit of a struggle I can sign in with FBConnect, I can get stuff from the FBSession, like the users name, and I can logout. But, the README on the plugin site seems to suggest that following the five steps will result in the FB UID being saved in your local database (presumably against a user it will have created), but there's nothing in the docs or code that indicates how this will actually happen. What I want is that when a user signs in using FBConnect, I either match or create a new user for them.  From then on I can use current_user in my controllers and views as normal (so that current_user.id is their local id, not their facebook id, since I want multiple forms of authentication), but if I want facebook stuff for that user I can access it easily, maybe with something like current_user.fb_user.

Has anyone been able to do this? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what Authlogic is suppose to do! One thing that was missing from the doc when I installed the facebook plugin was the need to add a `facebook_session_key` column in the users table :

```
add_column :users, :facebook_session_key, :string
```

Did you add this column?